# Multiple ImageButtons for one purpose in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I have a number of camera icons next to multiple questions. This way if the user has to take a picture to document the answer they can. This all takes place inside a fragment. I have the following code

```
public class PostInstallation extends Fragment {
View view;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pre_installation, container,
            false);

    ImageButton camera = (ImageButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.pre_install_camera);     

    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });     

    return view;
}
}
```

It works beautifully, no problems. However I am stumped on how I could add 10 more of these `ImageButtons` efficiently. Do I have to use something like this?

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
 button3.setOnClickListener(this);


 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()) {
       case R.id.button1:
       // do stuff;
       break;
       case R.id.button2:
       // do stuff;
       break;
   ...
}
}
```

and if I do does that mean in a fragment I would actually have to call this statement over and over for all `ImageButtons`?

```
button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this.view);
```

The reason I ask is because the switch statement seems redundant seeing how all these buttons do the ***exact same thing***. They all just call the camera. I'm positive others have run into this and found a more efficient/elegant solution. Thanks in advance!

**Working Code**

This is what I ended up settling on using, I will upvote and welcome all new posts in this thread that get this done with less code. I'm all about less code. Thanks!

```
public class PostInstallation extends Fragment {
View view;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_installation, container,
            false);

    ImageButton camera = (ImageButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
    ImageButton camera2 = (ImageButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.camera_button2);
    ImageButton camera3 = (ImageButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.camera_button3);
    ImageButton camera4 = (ImageButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.camera_button4);

    OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {            

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    };

    camera.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    camera2.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    camera3.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    camera4.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);     

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create just one Listener and add it to all the buttons.

```
OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        takePicutre()
    }
}
view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
view.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
view.findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
```

Comment: haha, I knew it was something simple. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you my friend

Comment: This is basically same as your own solution.

Comment: @shoe rat it is but it isnt, I was looking to mainly avoid making multiple image button listeners. Declaring each button seemed unavoidable without some kind of loop

Answer (score 1):

Give same ID for all of your buttons in your layout.

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pre_install_camera"
        ....
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pre_install_camera"
        ....
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pre_install_camera"
        ....
        />
    ....
```

Comment: I just had that same thought (see the edited post), I may use this, I may use Simon's but as he was first I accepted his answer. Thank you very much though!

Comment: just so you know this doesn't work. I wish it did because it would save a lot of typing. However Android only recognizes the first instance of the ID, all other buttons with the same ID don't react to the OnClick method